# Two the same models in one view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having one form in my website. The form contains information about two localizations. First localization called FROM and second called TO.
In my view I am using

```
@model DDP.Models.Localization
```

Here is my Localization entity:

```
public class Localization
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Province { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    public string StreetAdres { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I want pass to my controller two instances of Localization like below:

```
public ActionResult AddRoute(Localization from, Localization to)
{
    return View();
}
```

There is problem when I want to do it like below because I have two the same models.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.City, new { @id = "cityFrom", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Miasto", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" })
```

Can somone show me right direction?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a viewModel hosting the two instances, and use that into your view.

```
namespace DDP.ViewModels
{
    public class vm
    {
        Localization L1 {get; set;}
        Localization L2 {get; set;}
    }
}
```

and use it into your view like this:

```
public ActionResult AddRoute(Localization from, Localization to)
    {
        DDP.ViewModels.vm ret = new DDP.ViewModels.vm() { L1 = from, L2 = to};
        return View(ret);
    }


@model DDP.ViewModels.vm

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.L1.City, new { @id = "cityFrom", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Miasto", @style = "margin-bottom: 10px;" })
```

**(I didn't actually test the code, I just typed it here into the editor maybe there's some mistake but hopefully it should put you onto the right way!)**